# How to type in Python a function of signature (T, Sequence[T]) -> int including str?

Tags: python, mypy

I would like to type a simple count function counting a given element occurrences in a sequence. This gives no mypy error which surprises me since str is not a Sequence[str] or is it ?

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Sequence

T = TypeVar('T')

def count(x: T, xs: Sequence[T], acc: int = 0) -> int:
    if len(xs) == 0:
        return acc
    else:
        return count(x, xs[1:], acc + (1 if x == xs[0] else 0))


print(count("a", "abracadabra"))
print(count(1, (1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1)))
print(count(1, range(10)))
print(count(1, [i for i in range(10)]))
```

Comment: Yes, a string is a sequence. That's why you can  do `for char in string:`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you _wouldn't_ want `str` to count in this case? For most purposes, a string can be treated the same as an immutable `list` of characters - iteration, slicing, builtins like `reversed()`/`sorted()`, etc.

Comment: What looks strange is that x being a str, str is the type of the element and the sequence of this type of element : T = Sequence[T]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not differentiate between character and string, like other typed languages do.

Characters are just str objects of length 1, so a str is a Sequence[str] in the sense of Sequence[character].

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad that `str = Sequence[str]` here which gives more genericity to the `count` function.

Comment: I can [see](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/README.txt) that there is a `char` type (`STRINGLIB_CHAR`) in `cpython` distinct from `str` (`STRINGLIB_CHAR*`). I guess typing came long after the chr=str decision.

Comment: The typing module was introduced in Python 3.5, so it is a very recent thing.